Can you still do grapple checks with athletics in 5e 2024?
I'm playing a game that started with 2014 but moving into the 2024 system. One thing that had come up is grappling. I had a barbarian with expertise in athletics who uses grapple checks to hold his enemy in place and beat 'em to death.
I know the new rules for unarmed strikes in 2024 allow you to replace the damage from an unarmed strike to a grapple. However some folks in the group tells me that this is the new mechanic for grappling, and the 2024 no longer uses opposed checks for that.
I don't agree since unarmed strikes have nothing to do with skill checks and don't see why an attack replaces a skill check, and the DM agrees with me.
Does 2024 version of 5e no longer use athletic check to grapple?

Related: Can you grapple a creature as an Opportunity Attack?

No
As you have pointed out yourself, the rules for grappling are different in the 2024 rules. It is now the target that makes a save instead of an opposed skill check. A Strength (Athletics) or Dexterity (Acrobatics) check is still used to escape a grapple (against the grappler's grapple DC).
One consequence of this is that it is no longer possible to focus your character build on maximizing grapple checks as with the 2014 rules. There are some feats that help grappling (Tavern Brawler, Grappler and Unarmed Fighting), but they don't increase your chances of succeeding on the actual grapple. In other words: Building an effective grappler in the 2014 rule set is fundamentally different than in the 2024 rule set. If your barbarian has built a character focused on grappling in the 2014 rules, that build is no longer an effective grappler under the 2024 rules. It could be a bummer to "lose" that mid campaign when changing rule sets. House ruling that the old way is still possible, or that Athletics affects the DC in some way, could be a good idea to let the barbarian keep the benefits of his build.
